# How to use pd.DatetimeIndex within a function

Tags: pandas, datetime, vectorization

I have some datetime64[ns] data in a pandas column

```
datetime = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2020, 2, 11, 2, 17), periods=20, freq=pd.DateOffset(seconds=1))

df= pd.DataFrame(datetime,columns=['datetime'])
```

I want to create a column converting this to Julian day, this works in Pandas

```
df['julianday1'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime']).to_julian_date()
```

However - I want to do this (and then more) and embed it in a function

```
def jday(dtinput=None):
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(dtinput).to_julian_date()
```

When I call the function:

```
df['julianday2'] = np.vectorize(jday)(dtinput=df['datetime'])
```

I get the error message:

```
TypeError: DatetimeIndex() must be called with a collection of some kind, numpy.datetime64('2020-02-11T02:17:00.000000000') was passed
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: according to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), `DatetimeIndex` expects `data` to be array-like. so it is the expected behavior that you get into trouble if you pass a scalar value. `pd.DatetimeIndex([np.datetime64('2020-02-11T02:17:00.000000000')]).to_julian_date()` works fine.

Comment: If I change my function to incorporate np.datetime64():

    def jday(dtinput=None):
        return pd.DatetimeIndex(np.datetime64(dtinput)).to_julian_date()

I still get the same error message

TypeError: DatetimeIndex() must be called with a collection of some kind, numpy.datetime64('2020-02-11T02:17:00.000000000') was passed

Comment: this seems to be related to `np.vectorize`, it seems to pass values to the function not arrays... `df['julianday2'] = jday(df['datetime'])` works fine for me (except the deprecation warning).

Comment: you're right - I'll take it! Bit confused over the np.vectorise though - works fine for me with other functions not involving pd.DatetimeIndex. Thanks for your help.